# GoogleVis - hide the display of the column but keep the underlying data for use

Tags: r, google-visualization

I'm starting to use googleVis in an R package. My problem is that I can't find a solution for hiding unwanted columns in columnchart which I want to use on event listener handlers. On my column chart I would like to show only columns of milk_yiel_305 and milk_yield_lactation. At the same time I want to pass a seqvence_id which would be used as a parameter in jscode.

Here is my code:

/*************** example code *********************************************************/

```
library(googleVis)

# experimental data
df=data.frame(lactation=c("1", "2", "3", "4","5"), 
seqvence_id=c(2758829,3735102,4751006,5826611,7059361), 
milk_yiel_305=c(5867,8147,8050,7904,6326),
milk_yield_lactation=c(5867,8147,8875,9308,6326))

# Java script for look up of detailed lactation data (milk recordings) 
jscode <- "window.open('https://www.govedo.si/pls/govedo/!portal_pkg.izpis?p_lak_id_seq='+data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row,0)+'&e=1&p_procedura=portal2_pkg.rpt_izpis_kontrol2&p_menu=SI'); "

#name of the graph, because of reason that I will use many of then on the same page
v_graph_name <- gsub(" ","",paste("L",parameter1))

#column chart
Lactation_bars <- gvisColumnChart(df, xvar="lactation", yvar=c("seqvence_id","milk_yiel_305","milk_yield_lactation"), 
chartid=v_graph_name,
options=list(
              width=550, 
              height=390,
              displayAnnotations=TRUE,
              gvis.listener.jscode=jscode,
              series= "{0:{color: 'green', visibleInLegend: true}, 1:{color: 'blue', visibleInLegend: true}}",
              vAxis="{title:'kg mleka',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize:12}}",
              hAxis="{title:'Zaporedna laktacija',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize:12}}",
              vAxis.viewWindowMode='maximized',
              legend='in'
              )
                                  )
plot(Lactation_bars) 

#file wher I save Html for later use in Oracle Web Application  

#cat(iconv(gsub(pattern = "UTF-8", replacement = "windows-1250",
#createGoogleGadget(Editor )), "ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8"), file=ime_datoteke)
```

/*************** end of  example code **************************************************/

Thanks for your prompt response.